# K3b to split volume across media

Tags: iso, split, mkisofs

How do I get K3b to split a volumes across several media?
For example if I give it a folder that has 6 GB (not one file of 6 GB), it should create several discs of 4.4 GB automatically, instead of me doing it manually?

If K3B can't do it, is there any software that can?

Comment: Almost the same question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10158/4319 ; however, it doesn't mention k3b.

Comment: This question could probably be made broader by asking how to split an ISO9660 image across several limited-size images. This is more useful and easier to deal with rather than "how to make this specific incarnation of a CD/DVD authoring frontend do the splitting".

Answer (score 2):

I would say that there is no software for this task since no software can compute the semantics of the files on your CD-image. How should K3B know which files have to be kept together?

If the order of the files is not important - I would use `tar` and `split` for the task - like I did when floppies were still in use...

Comment: Yup. That's the way the OP could go with Ivan's pointer, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10158/4319. The interesting thing is that, after doing some research, I see `mkisofs` does have options for volumes, but does not support volumes with more than one disk... Believing in the manpage, this would be *the* desired feature. Sadly, as many tools just rely on `mkisofs`, I'd guess it's not likely that some other burning tool does actually offer this feature.